# Iterating the std::list through a const_iterator

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

is it possible to iterate through until the end of list in main() function using the const_iterator? I tried using iter->end() but i can't figure it out.

```
#include <list>
#include <string>
using std::list;
using std::string;

class list_return
{
public:
list <string>::const_iterator get_list()
{
_list.push_back("1");
_list.push_back("2");
_list.push_back("3");
return _list.begin();
 }
 private:
list <string> _list;
};

int main()  
{  
   list_return lr;

   list <string>::const_iterator iter = lr.get_list();

   //here, increment the iterator until end of list

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You seem to have 'encapsulated' the list without exposing a way to access the `end()` method of the list which you need for your iteration to know when to finish. If you add a method that returns `_list.end()` to your `list_return` class (I've called it get_list_end) you could do something like this:

```
for (std::list<std::string>::const_iterator iter = lr.get_list();
        iter != lr.get_list_end();
        ++iter)
{
    //... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no automatic way to know the end of the list given an iterator. You need a function which returns the end of the list. You can provide something like like `const_iterator get_list_end()`.